# When I know the vertex's coordinates, can I choose a vertex as the coordinate and paint a color for each vertex? I want to color each vertex

Tags: python, scripting, vertices, color

I know the coordinates of every vertex in the model. At this time, I want to color each vertex. I am curious how to select a vertex through coordinates and how to paint a color after selecting a vertex.

Comment: Vertex colors are a bit more involved than just knowing which vertex they belong to, because they actually belong to a loop (one vertex and 2 edges). One vertex can be associated to multiple vertex colors, depending on the number of faces it is linked to. Could you elaborate a bit more on your current setup and your goal ?

Comment: Color each vertex, not the edge and the face, so the faces and edges between them should be connected with the color specified for the vertex. Before trying the results of a complex model, I create a simple cube and color each vertex. It is possible to color each vertex with a brush, but I want to do it with python code (the number of vertices of the model to be loaded is too many).
I currently go to edit mode to select vertex. I think I can paint colors by selecting each vertex, but I'm not sure